# Inapp purchase with maintain applications internal variable while user triying to install/ Uninstall application

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have developed one application Where user can have 4 trials available for free. when the user uses all the 4 trials and try to use one more trial application ask the user for In app purchase to spent 0.99 $ for another 4 trials.

I have used Consumable in app purchase model.

but the problem is when the user installing the application for first time user have 4 trials available for free. if user used 2 trials then user have 2 trials remaining. and user uninstalled the application and installed application again from appstore.when the user installed new application user have 4 trials available instead of 2 trials because apple allow user to download application 10 times once user had purchased product once with the same Apple ID.

So Is there any way maintain the in app purchase state by which i will prevent the user to access the trial more than 4 times ?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO there is no sure way to do this.

You could save the trial state in the keychain, but if the user clears there iPhone the information is wiped.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you have the option to do that first for trails for any device you has to get use of "UDID" every time the user open the application you have to get the UDID and check on server if this UDID exist on the server for 4 times you will not load the application so the 4 trial times has been finished.

also for "inapppurchase" you have to make relation also between UDID if you don't support registration module and save every purchase on server side for this UDID so every time the user install or uninstall the app the same data can be retrieved again for that device..
Hope my answer helps you. thanks